# Source .bashrc in Ansible

Tags: shell, automation, ansible

Trying to source during run changes in .bashrc but

```
- name: Set the environment variable for the current session
  shell: "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/rc-binaries/"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash

- name: Source the updated .bashrc
  shell: "source {{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bashrc"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash

- name: Enable auto-completion for commands
  shell: "rc --autocompletion"
  ignore_errors: true
```

But as result:
No such file or directory: b'rc'

How it could be fixed?

Expect to be able to run binaries which we define in Path in next Ansible task

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "updated .bashrc", but can't you run `rc`  via `shell: "bash -i  'rc --autocompletion'"`? The `-i` should cause .bashrc to be processed. BTW, it's IMO bad design to put settings intended for non-interactive shells into .bashrc, which is intended for configuring interactive shells.

Comment: The idea was to use updated bashrc in all next tasks

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted, which would update your .bashrc. However, since the core problem seems to be to run a bash process which uses the current .bashrc, whatever it is, did you try my suggestion? I don't have ansible and can not test whether it would work; otherwise I would have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each task runs in a separate process. Setting shell or environment variables in one task will have absolutely no effect on subsequent tasks. You would need to perform all those actions in a single task:

```yaml
- shell: |
    export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/rc-binaries/
    source {{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bashrc
    rc --autocompletion
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  ignore_errors: true
```

Comment: That worked, tahnk you

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!